# Como bloquear o click em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu estou tentando bloquear o click em um `input`

**Html**

```
<input id="txtData" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon" data-role="data"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
```

De forma que não aconteça nenhuma ação quando o `input` for clicado, já tentei o seguinte código e não obtive sucesso.

```
$('#txtData').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

*obs: já tentei com `delegate` e `onclick` também.

Eu tenho um `datepicker` acoplado no `input`, ele é acionado quando eu clico em outro lugar (`$('#txtData').datepicker("show");`), já procurei também propriedades do `datepicker`e não tem nenhuma que deixe ele invisível ou algo do tipo, possivelmente o click aciona o `datepicker` antes de executar a minha função `jquery`, teria alguma forma de bloquear 100% o click, antes, durante e depois, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tentou as propriedades `disabled` ou `readonly` do proprio HTML?

Comment: Acabei de tentar, mudou o cursor como o campo estivesse bloqueado mesmo, mas continua abrindo o datepicker, que loucura.

Comment: Tentou remover o evento do click dela? Porque como você usa um datepicker nele, o datepicker vai anexar o evento click quando for carregado.

Comment: Mas eu preciso do datepicker nele, mas eu só quero acionar o datepicker a partir de outro lugar, ex: clicar em um botão na tela, abrir ele a partir de outro lugar já to conseguindo o problema é que não queria abrir ao clicar no input mesmo, se eu tiro o datepicker do input ai nada mais funciona e se eu coloco o datepicker no botão que eu quero ele abre todo desformatado. @AndréLuisMarmo

Comment: Você pode não atribuir o datepicker a ele, já que quer abrir em outro lugar, e no evento do datepicker de: onSelect, setar a data selecionada..

Comment: Eu preciso atribuir o datepicker a ele pois ao selecionar uma data a data vai ser exibida no input, e atribuindo o datepicker a um botão por exemplo ele fica completamente desformatado.@Aline

Comment: Não tem como elaborar um exemplo mínimo e verificável para incluir na pergunta? Utilizar o snippet de HTML do SOpt pode ser uma boa.

Comment: Sim, vou fazer isso, no momento não posso, mas assim que der vou complementar a pergunta com um snippet. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: A princípio o `disabled` deveria funcionar: [veja](https://repl.it/GQSF/0).

Comment: No datepicker tu tem uma opção: onSelect, é só pegar o valor e atribuir ao inpt quando o usuário selecionar.

Comment: Kd o Bacco com o link do problema XY?  :) O problema parece q é desativar um botão que ativa o Date Picker.  Não poderia de repente esconder ele inteiro com um display:none ou visibility:hidden do css e depois dar um display:block ou visibility:visible quando ele tivesse que aparecer?

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer o que você precisa apenas com CSS, essa propriedade garante que o elemento nunca vai ser alvo de eventos do mouse.

#### CSS FILE

```
#txtData {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, continua abrindo o datepicker ao clicar no input.

Comment: Tem certeza que não há uma div ou algo por cima do input que abre o datePicker? Porque a menos que você esteja utilizando um browser antigo essa propriedade é pra funcionar. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui e funcionou, falta você testar ai, abraço!
https://jsfiddle.net/ccmq8eub/1/

```
  $("#txtDataBlocked").focus(function(){
      $("#txtDataBlocked").off("click");
      $('#txtData').datepicker("hide");
  });


  $("#txtDataBlocked").click(function(){
      return false;
      alert("Clicado!!");
      $('#txtData').datepicker("hide");
  });
```

Comment: +1 realmente, seu código funciona, mas talvez essa minha pergunta foi mal formulada, descobri que meu problema se encontrava em um plugin de data que eu estava usando e respondi a sua também, de qualquer forma, muito obrigado .

Answer (score 0):

Bom, os códigos acima funcionam, mas já que o problema é abrir o `datepicker`, você pode alem disso desabilitar o próprio `datepicker`.

Acrescente

```
var tag = document.getElementByTagName('span');
tag.data-role = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Disabled" pode te ajudar

```
<input disabled id="txtData" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon" data-role="data"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
```